# Failed downloads in a multi-project build configuration in SBT 0.13.1?

Tags: sbt, ivy

We have our project setup very similar to [how twitter has their finagle project configured](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/master/project/Build.scala) with multiple projects and a single `project/Build.scala` file.

Any time we run a build we have to remove the Ivy cache otherwise some of the dependencies fail to download.

We've tried turning off all parallel execution (we figured it was some sort of conflict/lock timeout issue) but that doesn't seem to solve it either.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
[FAILED     ] com.example#helloworld_2.10;5.5.4-SNAPSHOT!helloworld_2.10.jar:
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
:: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: com.example#helloworld_2.10;5.5.4-SNAPSHOT!helloworld_2.10.jar
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: com.example#helloworld_2.10;5.5.4-SNAPSHOT!helloworld_2.10.jar
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:60)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:101)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:97)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1161)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1159)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1182)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1180)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1184)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1179)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1187)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1152)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1130)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
error (config/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: com.example#helloworld_2.10;5.5.4-SNAPSHOT!helloworld_2.10.jar
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider showing your build script and project layout. This may help people a lot to provide you with an answer.

Comment: Agree, we probably can't help you without more details. It would especially helpful if you could reduce it to a minimized failing case, so we could easily try it on our own machines.

Comment: Is `com.example#helloworld_2.10;5.5.4-SNAPSHOT!helloworld_2.10.jar` a build artifact of a submodule? How does the `project/Build.scala` look like?

Comment: Example [build file](https://gist.github.com/matterkkila/b09376e7920b773c151f)

Comment: I have a similar problem but removing the cache doesn't even seem to fix it. The jar is there is ~/.ivy2... but sbt/ivy just fail to see it for some reason.  Any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find the definition of `myResolvers` as in the following assignment:

```
resolvers := myResolvers
```

Also, the following won't work:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.example" %% "helloworld" % "5.5.4-SNAPSHOT" changing(),
)
```

The reason for failure in the above example is that there's the comma after `changing()`.

You don't need `changing()` for `SNAPSHOT` versions. See [Notes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Dependency-Management-Flow.html#notes) in the SBT documentation about Dependency Management Flow:

> There is no need to mark SNAPSHOT dependencies as changing() because
>   sbt configures Ivy to know this already.

Comment: Sorry, the resolvers and extra comma were left overs from me removing a ton of extra stuff that we can't release.  The real build file is ~300 lines long and isn't something I can post.  Although I didn't know that about changing, I'll remove that and see what happens.